# Mayavi: Poor rendering (aliasing) under linux

Tags: python, linux, mayavi

I wrote some mayavi code to visualise lines and images on Windows over the weekend. When I returned to my linux work-desk I was thoroughly disappointed running the same script. Execution time was a lot slower (it pas partly fixed by temporarily disabling the rendering in mayavi) and the output was aliased. I ran glmark2 to test my graphics card without problems.

What can I do to get better rendering results in mayavi?

### Mayavi output

Linux - aliased lines:

[image: Low quality output from Mayavi under Linux]

Windows - lines are a bit smoother:

[image: Medium quality output from Mayavi under Windows]

### Glmark2 results

```
=======================================================
    glmark2 2012.08
=======================================================
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     Intel Open Source Technology Center
    GL_RENDERER:   Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Desktop 
    GL_VERSION:    3.0 Mesa 10.0.0
=======================================================
[build] use-vbo=false: FPS: 2544 FrameTime: 0.393 ms
[build] use-vbo=true: FPS: 2463 FrameTime: 0.406 ms
[texture] texture-filter=nearest: FPS: 2775 FrameTime: 0.360 ms
[texture] texture-filter=linear: FPS: 2267 FrameTime: 0.441 ms
[texture] texture-filter=mipmap: FPS: 2179 FrameTime: 0.459 ms
[shading] shading=gouraud: FPS: 1152 FrameTime: 0.868 ms
[shading] shading=blinn-phong-inf: FPS: 1051 FrameTime: 0.951 ms
[shading] shading=phong: FPS: 1068 FrameTime: 0.936 ms
[bump] bump-render=high-poly: FPS: 520 FrameTime: 1.923 ms
[bump] bump-render=normals: FPS: 2249 FrameTime: 0.445 ms
[bump] bump-render=height: FPS: 1900 FrameTime: 0.526 ms
[effect2d] kernel=0,1,0;1,-4,1;0,1,0;: FPS: 1112 FrameTime: 0.899 ms
[effect2d] kernel=1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1;: FPS: 466 FrameTime: 2.146 ms
[pulsar] light=false:quads=5:texture=false: FPS: 1550 FrameTime: 0.645 ms
[desktop] blur-radius=5:effect=blur:passes=1:separable=true:windows=4: FPS: 394 FrameTime: 2.538 ms
[desktop] effect=shadow:windows=4: FPS: 691 FrameTime: 1.447 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=false:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=map: FPS: 530 FrameTime: 1.887 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=false:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=subdata: FPS: 559 FrameTime: 1.789 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=true:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=map: FPS: 558 FrameTime: 1.792 ms
[ideas] speed=duration: FPS: 1108 FrameTime: 0.903 ms
[jellyfish] <default>: FPS: 797 FrameTime: 1.255 ms
[terrain] <default>: FPS: 101 FrameTime: 9.901 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=0:vertex-steps=0: FPS: 1646 FrameTime: 0.608 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=5:vertex-steps=0: FPS: 1796 FrameTime: 0.557 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=0:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 1617 FrameTime: 0.618 ms
[function] fragment-complexity=low:fragment-steps=5: FPS: 1644 FrameTime: 0.608 ms
[function] fragment-complexity=medium:fragment-steps=5: FPS: 1796 FrameTime: 0.557 ms
[loop] fragment-loop=false:fragment-steps=5:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 1695 FrameTime: 0.590 ms
[loop] fragment-steps=5:fragment-uniform=false:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 1709 FrameTime: 0.585 ms
[loop] fragment-steps=5:fragment-uniform=true:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 1697 FrameTime: 0.589 ms
=======================================================
                                  glmark2 Score: 1387 
=======================================================
```

### Update

I have updated my system with a Nvidia N450GTS graphics card and I am currently using the proprietary NVIDIA drivers (NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-337.19.run). The output is still severely aliased and, as I later found out, contains incorrect z-order elements as seen in these images:

[image: angle without z-order problems]
[image: z-order problems]

Comment: This problem almost certainly has to do with the graphics driver. What graphics card are you using? I use nvidia cards and sometimes people have yelled at me about binary blobs, and then later come to me with problems like this.

Comment: `>>> inxi -Gx

Card: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
bus-ID: 00:02.0
X.Org: 1.14.5 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) 
Resolution: 1920x1080@60.0hz, 1920x1080@60.0hz 
GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Desktop 
GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.0.0 
Direct Rendering: Yes`

Comment: @aestrivex I see my z-ordering is also broken. I thing you are correct, but I have no idea how to fix my graphics drivers. I am not afraid of binary blobs, but I have already installed the Intel drivers. :( Windows suck at c++ compilation and Linux suck at graphics (sometime you get lucky). Maybe I should just get a mac for a unix system with decent build-essentials and drivers (or so I have heard).

Comment: I recommend nvidia cards for any linux setup. nvidia provides binary drivers that have worked flawlessly for a decade. not that that helps you here.

Comment: @aestrivex Thanks for the advice. Just my luck, I see there is a N450GTS laying around in my lab. I will connect the baby up and give some feedback.

Comment: Is there any other way to improve the mayavi graphics? I'm using it in my application and my observation is that, it is not at par with the commercial software.

Comment: Hi @Simon Streicher, Did you ever found a solution for this? I run into the same issue :).

Comment: @Stefan no sorry, for this project I ended up moving away from mayavi and over to Matlab for better 3D rendering support